# git create commit from diff between two branches

Tags: git

I have two branches which have very little similar history, but are related to each other.

I want the changes between those two in **one** git commit.

files have been deleted and created between those patches and I want the patch to reflect that

i.e.: the following stuff will not work:

```
git diff branch_a branch_b -- > patchfile
git checkout branch_b
git apply patchfile # deletes and adds are ignored
git commit # we miss the deletes
```

Answer (score 173, accepted):

A simple way to make "the diff from branch_b..branch_a" into a commit is:

1. create and checkout branch tmp at branch_a (`git branch tmp branch_a && git checkout tmp`) (or `git reset --hard branch_a` on an existing branch)
2. `git reset --soft branch_b`
3. `git commit`

that commit will include all the diff between branch_b and branch_a.

---

This works because

- `1.` causes the files to reflect branch_a. This is the "end result" you want for the branch
- `2.` “resets the head to branch_b” but “leaves all your changed files [i.e. branch_a head] as "Changes to be committed", as git `status` would put it.” *←([`git reset --soft` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---soft), with this example's branches added)*

Comment: you don't need a common commit or even touching the branches up front. just try doing it in gitk -- as you experiment on new branch that will be gone anyway you have a free run.

Comment: Worked for me using git 1.7.9.5

Comment: more precisely: git branch tmp branchA  && git checkout tmp && git reset --soft branchB && git checkout branchB && git branch -D tmp && git commit

Comment: branch b name has a typo, should be `to_branch_b`

Comment: that's `git reset --soft <branch_b>`, `git commit`

Answer (score 53):

If you have two branches:

1. `has-changes`
2. `needs-changes`

And you want to move the changes from `has-changes` onto `needs-changes`, then do the following:

```
git checkout -b deleteme has-changes # Create temporary branch to build commit on
git reset --soft needs-changes       # Move diff into index
git commit                           # Create the diff patch commit
git checkout needs-changes           # Switch to branch that needs changes
git cherry-pick deleteme             # Apply the diff to the needs-changes
git branch -D deleteme               # Delete the temporary branch
```

Comment: I find myself doing this often instead of dealing with a super hairy merge/rebase. Is this bad?

Comment: @Brett only thing you lose is the commit history on the original branch, like timestamps and commit messages, so as long as you're OK with that then there's nothing wrong with this at all. If you find you're doing this a lot though it may mean that you're branches are too long-lived, or you're not merging latest master in often enough, or your development process encourages you to make lots of unnecessary commits.

Comment: The key part is `git reset --soft needs-changes`. If you dare, you don't have to create an extra branch. If you merge with the needs-changes beforehand, you won't need the cherrypick either.

Comment: Yeah, if you're willing to make destructive changes to `has-changes` then you can eliminate the first and last lines.

Comment: I keep coming back here, great answer.

Answer (score 15):

It all comes down to a `git reset --soft branch_b` on top of a temp branch based on branch_a, and the result committed back to branch_b.

This is a step-by-step walking through the process:

```
#Start out on the branch with the code we want
git checkout branch_a

#create tmp branch same as branch_a (so that we don't change our local branch_a state during the operation)
git branch tmp

#working directory has all the code that we want, on tmp branch
git checkout tmp

# Change the branch head to the branch we want to be on. All the delta
# between the current source code and branch_b is now staged for commit
git reset --soft branch_b

# Move away from tmp, so our commit will go directly to branch_b
git checkout branch_b

# Now you can examine the proposed commit
git status

# Add the delta we want to the branch
git commit

# Sanity check that the branches have the same content now (should return an empty line)
git diff branch_A..branch_b

# Remove tmp, we don't need it anymore
git branch -D tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from your example, what you really want to achieve is to create a commit in `branch_b` that makes the state of the repository match exactly that of `branch_a`.

In that case, `git commit-tree` will do the job:

```bash
new_commit=$(git commit-tree -p branch_b -m "my message" branch_a^{tree})
git branch --force branch_b $new_commit
```

In the commands above, we first create a new commit with `branch_b` as the parent and with the same state of the repository as that of `branch_a`. We then capture the object id of the new commit in the variable `new_commit` to finally have `branch_b` point to this new commit, effectively obtaining the same outcome as if we had committed the difference between `branch_b` and `branch_a` to `branch_b`.

Note that `git branch` will fail if we are already checked out at `branch_b`. In that case, we can use `git reset` instead:

```bash
git reset $new_commit  # use --hard to also reset working directory
```

Another more traditional approach is to leverage `git diff` in combination with `git apply`:

```bash
git checkout branch_b
git diff --binary branch_b branch_a | git apply --index
git commit -m "my message"
```

This, however, might fail depending on the state of your working tree, as existing untracked or unstaged changes might cause conflicts when applying the patch.