# How can I make a git commit that represents the diff between two other commits?

Tags: git, diff, cherry-pick

I'm currently working on a git branch based off of branch `main` with a `HEAD` of commit `A`. I realized I wanted to split the work I was doing into two PRs, but I want to preserve the history properly.  An idea I had was to `git reset --soft main`, unstage the parts I want to separate out, and commit the remaining bits so `HEAD` is now one commit ahead of `main` on commit `B`.

Ideally, at this stage, I would like to `git reset --hard A` and make a commit on top of it that gets me to working state in commit `B`.  However, I can't figure out a way to add a commit that is the diff between `A` and `B`.

Does anyone have an idea for how I can make this commit, essentially removing all of the stuff from my branch that I wanted to separate out?

Comment: I'm not sure I read your question correctly: is your goal to end up with the content of `A` ( the initial complete commit) on top ? or the content of `B`  (the "partial" commit) ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `git rebase` to solve this.

1. Make a branch corresponding to commit A.

   ```
   git branch branch-A
   ```
2. Switch to a branch B and commit your changes

   ```
   git checkout -b branch-B
   git add ...  # Add your changes
   git commit
   ```
3. Rewrite branch B to not include branch A.

   ```
   git rebase -i main
   # When the text editor pops up, remove the commit from branch B which is already committed to branch B.
   # Leave the commit which is only on branch B.
   # Save your changes.
   ```
4. You now have two branches, branch-A and branch-B, each of which only contain one commit.

Comment: The problem here is that I want to preserve the `main` thru `A` history in `branch-B`.  I want `branch-A` to remain as it was and `branch-B` to be `branch-A` +1 commit which brings me to the state in `commit B`.

Comment: @MattHauff If the two have commits in common which aren't present in main, doesn't that contradict your goal of separating the two PRs?

Comment: I want `branch-A` to gain a commit that removes all of the now separate stuff.  This is now a smaller, more reviewable PR.  I would then like to make a new branch (`branch-B`) which reverses the operation (gains a commit that adds all of the previously removed stuff.) Once `branch-A` is merged to main and `branch-B` is pointed to main to merge, `branch-B` will look like only the stuff that was removed from `branch-A` and added back to `branch-B`.

Comment: @MattHauff That sounds like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324645/git-create-commit-from-diff-between-two-branches).

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I forgot that `git reset` worked for commits not in the history of the current branch too.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a commit with *the exact content of A* on top of B.

This can be done in several ways, one of which is:

```
# from commit B:

# restore content of A:
git restore --staged --worktree --source A -- .
# or using shorthand:
git restore -SW -s A -- .

# commit:
git commit
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, if you want to end up in state `B` on top of `A`, just switch `A` and `B` above